# ADS1x15 Python library

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, i2c, adc

Let's say I have an ADS1015 ADC converter and a Raspberry Pi. In my project I only need to read the values of an analog sensor.

This is the library written in Python for this ADC converter for Raspberry Pi: [ADS1015 github repository](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15)

Let's take as an example `sampletest.py`:

```
import time
import Adafruit_ADS1x15

adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

print('Reading ADS1x15 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')

print('| {0:>6} | {1:>6} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} |'.format(*range(4)))
print('-' * 37)

while True:
    values = [0]*4
    for i in range(4):
        values[i] = adc.read_adc(i, gain=GAIN)
    print('| {0:>6} | {1:>6} | {2:>6} | {3:>6} |'.format(*values))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I need to know very precisely what's the sample rate I get on my computer. I know that I can set the sample rate of the ADC anywhere from 64 up to 3200, but whenever I read from the computer, there's a slight delay before the data comes.

For example: if I set the sample rate of the chip at 128 and in Python let's say I delay the reading by 1/60 seconds (so we have a theoretical sample rate of 60 sps), what would the actual sample rate on the computer be? (i.e. 59, 57 etc) And does the waiting time get smaller if I choose a higher sample rate of the ADC? (like 256 sps)

At the moment, I don't have the ADC converter to make tests, so I ask you here.

Answer (score 0):

For the ADS1015 specifically, there exist 2 different modes it can operate in:

- Single-Shot
- Continues-Conversion

### Single-Shot mode

In Single-Shot mode, the ADC is in a power-down state until u ask it for a conversion of the current voltage applied. The ADS1015 then needs to power up (taking roughly 25µs) and samples the voltage.

If you want to determine the sample rate for this mode, you need to add the time it takes for the ADS1015 to perform the conversion.

```
SR = 1 / (t_python + t_conversion)
```

If we now decrease the time it takes the ADS1015 to make the conversion, we can increase the sample rate of our python program.

### Continues-Conversion mode

In Continues-Conversion mode, the ADS1015 is constantly sampling data at the specified sample rate.

Determining the sample rate for this mode is a bit more complicated than for the Single-Shot case. This is due to the fact that the python program and the ADS1015 are now operating truly asynchronous.

There are now 2 cases:

1. We want to read where there is a conversion ready
2. We want to read when the ADS1015 updates the conversion register

Case 1 is pretty simple, as this just means we don't need to wait for the conversion of the ADC:

```
SR = 1 / (t_python)
```

Case 2 means we need to wait for the conversion to finish, which in the worst case could take up to t_conversion time

```
SR = 1 / (t_python + t_remainingConversion)
```

with

```
0 < t_remainingConversion < t_conversion
```

### Code example

Your given example is based on the Adafruit library for the ADS1015.
The `adc_read` function exclusively operates the ADS1015 in Single-Shot mode, which is quite slow, because of the 25µs start up. It also just waits a specified time based on the sample rate for the result of the conversion.

One optimizing that could be implemented is the usage of the ALERT/RDY pin to notify that a conversion is ready.

---

All the information concerning the ADS1015 can be found in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1015), which in general is highly recommended to read (or skim if you want a quick overview) for any electrical component.